# Hashing and signing partial data in payload

Tags: encryption, hash, digital-signature

I'm hashing and signing part of a payload prior to HTTP Posting from a mobile device to server side. The payload contains of about 7 data elements and only 3 of them are hashed/signed using a private key (RSA) then base 64 encoded and sent to server side. The 3 data elements are sent as a separate param and server is aware of the order of the elements in that param. On server side, after decoding I'm validating the signature (of the 3 data elements) using the public key and if it is successful then I trust all the 7 data elements (aka the entire doc). The question is it safe to trust all the 7 data elements? Or should I hash/sign all the 7 data elements in the doc prior to trusting/using the data.

Thanks

Comment: Any reason you're not just using SSL/TLS to secure the transport?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cryptographic signature can only assert trust on the data it is signing. Unless there's a way to validate the validity of the unsigned fields based on the validity of the signed fields, then no you can't trust the unsigned fields.

Comment: Yeah, unless I'm missing something here this is pretty obvious.